# Running into an error with getting music bot to join VC

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
name: 'play',
description: "plays music in voice chat",
async execute(message, args, Discord){
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
  
    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel to listen to music!');
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.reply("You don't have the correct permissions to request music!");
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.reply("You don't have the correct permissions to request music!");
    if (!args.length) return message.channel.send("You Can't Request for no Music Silly >_<");

  const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

  const videoFinder = async (query) => {
      const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

      return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;

    }
    const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
    if(video){
      const stream = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
      connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
      .on('finish', () =>{
          voiceChannel.leave();
      });



      await message.reply(`:Thumbsup: Now Playing >>>${video.title}<<<`)
    } else {
      message.reply('No Video Results Found :(');
    }
  }
}
```

My Error message is   const connection = await voiceChannel.join();

TypeError: voiceChannel.join is not a function

If any of you have a suggestion that may work please feel free to edit it. It can also only detect if someone is in voice chat at start up of the bot, so if your in voice chat at start of bot it sends the in voice chat message while your in and out of voice chat

Comment: What version of Discord.js are you using? I don't know much about discord bots in particular, but it looks like, from most of their examples, they have switched over to TS and have also abstracted 'voice' into its own package. If you're using a newer version, I'd suggest learning a little TS and using that. It would have caught the error before compiling :)

That being said, it looks like the 'voice' package doesn't have a "join" method, but rather uses a "subscription" object. See below:
https://github.com/discordjs/voice/blob/main/examples/music-bot/src/bot.ts

Comment: The above assumes you are using one of the newer versions of this package, since it wasn't otherwise mentioned in the OP.

Comment: I'm using the most recent version of discord.js, not sure how to check the release version number i downloaded it through npm

Comment: In that case, it would be the TS version I've come across as well. I'd recommend not using JS as much as you can help it, and switch over to using TS whenever possible. These types of errors would be caught ahead of time, before compilation. There are a few examples in the repo I shared above, as well as a ton of TS resources on google, so hopefully that helps. You're definitely welcome to keep using pure JS, but I'm afraid you may run into many similar issues going forward.

Comment: @NaturalTwitch Please give this question a more specific title so that it can be found more easily in future searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While transitioning from discord.js v12 - v13 we have encountered a breaking change that is switching to `@discordjs/voice` a seperate library for voice to play with discord.js, now as suggested from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081415/running-into-an-issue-with-a-discord-music-bot#comment122093779_69081415) here I see you're using the most latest version of discord.js where the `VoiceChannel#join` method no longer exists. You have to propose the following changes:

- Install `@discordjs/voice` using `npm install @discordjs/voice`
- You need to establish a  **[`voiceConnection`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/voiceconnection.html)**, and further create an **[`AudioPlayer`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/audioplayer.html)** instance and go ahead and call the **[`AudioPlayer#subscribe`](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/classes/playersubscription.html)** method to this player, you would have to do some base additions for the same which are exhibited below:

```js
const {
    joinVoiceChannel,
    createAudioPlayer,
    createAudioResource
} = require('@discordjs/voice');

const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
    guildId: message.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});

const stream = ytdl(video.url, {
    filter: "audioonly"
});

const player = createAudioPlayer();
const resource = createAudioResource(stream);

async function play() {
    await player.play(resource);
    connection.subscribe(player);
}
```

They just made it overcomplex for beginners to comprehend so don't worry! If you feel like you're over- exhausting yourselves you can always downgrade to a lower version like so:

```sh
npm uninstall discord.js
npm install discord.js@12.5.3
```

Welcome to stackoverflow